# sending an array through cURL POST

Tags: php, rest, curl, slim

Hi i am testing a scenario for REST web service for mobile app.During testing i need to send an array to my php programme using post method. which i am doing through cURL console. rest of the thing is working fine except passing an array. Please suggest any changes.

following code i am passing in cURL console

```
C:\curlw32>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost/slim-login/api/submit -d "{\"specialtyCheckbox\":\"[1,2,3]\"}"
```

and here is the php code for catching it

```
$request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
$onsubmit_content = json_decode($request->getBody());
$spec=$onsubmit_content->specialtyCheckbox;
echo json_encode(count($spec));
```

Here the length of the array it is showing 1.

Comment: Please have a look here: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/194255-curl-sending-array-as-post-value/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont use quotes around your array (if you want to send a json array ):

```
"{\"specialtyCheckbox\":[1,2,3]}"
```

Comment: It’s actually not you don’t _need_, but you __must not__ have them there ;-) `"[…]"` is nothing more than a text literal contains these characters.

Comment: true , but i was not sure what he expected ,since he says curl works on the cli.

Comment: Thanks mpm :) it worked!! actually i was passing it as string using quotes that's why it was showing its length as one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing your array through a PHP script( using CURL)

```
$ch = curl_init ($url); // your URL to send array data
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); // Your array field
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Sandy i don't need to run it through script as i am just testing it for web service which will be ultimately used by mobile app team.console is fine for me "less effort"!!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna pass the array over the **CURL** call the answer is very simple. Put all the input parameters in array like-

```
$post = array('prgmCode'=>'3',
                'userStateCode'=>'TA',
                );
```

If you need to pass an input array on this you can set

```
`$chkBoxArr = array(1,2,3,4);
$post = array('prgmCode'=>'3',
                'userStateCode'=>'TA',
                'chkBoxArr'=>$chkBoxArr
                );`
```

You can use function http_build_query() to make a query string from the array.

```
`$data = http_build_query($post);`
```

And set the data to your curl

```
`curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`
```

Check the request in the server side. Done. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try This

```
 curl -d '{"previous_questions":"['hello', 'world', 'finally']"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5000/quizzes
```